# Spring not giving current session without marking @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Using Spring sessionFactory injection.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void getData() {
        System.out.println("%%%% Hibernate fetching data %%%% ");
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        /*
         * try { Thread.sleep(10000); } catch (InterruptedException e) { // TODO
         * Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); }
         */
        List<Address> addresses = session.createQuery("from Address").list();
        System.out.println("Total Connectins = "
                + factory.getStatistics().getConnectCount());
        for (Address address : addresses) {
            System.out.println(address);
        }
    }
```

Above code is giving exception

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
```

But when this method is marked as **@Transactional** it's working fine.
But I don't want any transaction to be enabled for this method.

Am I missing anything..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats how transactions work. By marking that method `@Transactional`, you are asking the `TransactionManager` to create and start a new transaction with a new transactional session from the `SessionFactory`. Without a transaction, Hibernate doesn't create a `Session` with the database. The reason it creates a `Transaction` is that if something goes wrong, Hibernate can easily roll back things you did within the one transaction.

Without the `@Transactional`, Hibernate assumes that you don't need to interact with the database. I suggest reading the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) before proceeding because you seem to be quite confused as to how this technology works. A through understanding of what is going on will greatly increase your effectiveness when writing these sorts of things.